# How to extract content from AIR application?

Tags: air, adobe

There is an AIR magazine application that downloads it's content as you view it. I want to save a couple of pages on my local disk, is there a way to do it?
The App does't store anything in it's Application Contents folder (I'm on a Mac) or in ~/Library/Application Support/.

Thanks.